# OnTouchListener weird bug

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

When I use the `OnTouchListener` it only works if I add a command that says to do something like:

> tv.setText("");

For example:

```
  drawView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
             @Override
             public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
                tv.setText("");
                int x = ev.getX();

                return true;
            }
         });
```

If you would remove the line that says `tv.setText("");`, it won't work.. Any ideas?

Comment: what doesn't work?  have you added logging or set breakpoints to see what's going on?

Comment: why it should work, it will not work, first clarify what you want?

Answer (score 0):

if the flow of the program ones enter in onTouch then the whole method will be executed. That's the flow will keep executing statements until it reaches the closing bracket of the method or it find a return statement (in this case you must return true/false). Except whne you have some bug that produces exception then the normal flow in breaked and the exeption is thrown.

```
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
                tv.setText("");
                int x = ev.getX();

                return true;
            }
```

All I am trying to say is that if tv.setText(""); is executed then the int x = ev.getX(); is executed also.

This is small sniped to realize your problem but I think that you want to read the x variable from someone else in the code, and you have also defined global x variable so you expect that x variable to change its value. Well it wont cause here in onTouch you create another var with the same name x, and you change the value of the local var not the global one. You can check this with
Log.v("local var"," x=" +x);